headerStyle in react native not chaning the header color completely
This is the index.jsx
<NavigationContainer independent={true}>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName='Nav'>
        <Stack.Screen name="Nav" component={Nav}
          options={{
            title: "Welcome",
            headerStyle: {
              backgroundColor: '#f4511e',
            },
            headerTintColor: '#fff',
            headerTitleStyle: {
              fontWeight: 'bold',
            },
          }} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Form" component={Form} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginForm} />
        <Stack.Screen name="network" component={Networking} initialParams={{ name: "Guest" }} />
      </Stack.Navigator>

    </NavigationContainer>

This is the physical device's screenshot I am using.
There is a camera in the centre of the line where I have the time batter percentage etc.

Why is the colour not showing up in the top white strip?
And how to shift the welcome text closer to the top, I have tried it with headerTitleStyle only but nothing seems to work.

You need to make your status bar translucent.
import { StatusBar } from 'react-native';

// Inside your component
<StatusBar translucent />

